# javascript web workers - how do I pass arguments?

Tags: javascript

Found the answer some some of my problems, html5 web workers!!!

How do I pass an argument to a web worker though using this basic example?

contents of worker.js:

```
function doSomething() {
    postMessage( ' done');
}
setTimeout ( "doSomething()", 3000 );
```

js code:

```
 var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
  worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    alert(event.data);
  };
```

Comment: Use setTimeout like so: `setTimeout( doSomething, 3000 );` It's better because there is no extra evaluation going on...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As you can see you have the same mechanism for both worker-to-main and main-to-worker messages.

- the `postMessage` method for sending messages
- the `onmessage` member for defining the handler that receives the messages

In the main script:

```
worker.postMessage(data);
```

In the worker script:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    // the passed-in data is available via e.data
}, false);
```

... or just...

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    // the passed-in data is available via e.data
};
```

It may be that data has to be a string... (Firefox 3.5+ supports passing in JSON-compatible objects)

Comment: what is self there? in self.addEventListener?

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan The worker's global scope, like `window` on a web page. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453270.aspx

Comment: Probably you should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680502/3559690 as they have described a pretty nice way

Answer (score 0):

```
 var worker = new Worker(window.App.baseUrl + '/Scripts/signature/GetCurrenProductWorker.js');
                    worker.postMessage(window.App.baseUrl)


    var _base_url = ''
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        onmessage = function (e) {
            _base_url = e.data
            xhr.open("GET", _base_url + "/api/product/Get");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                postMessage(xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send();

        };
```

this work for me