# Can I pass parameters to .js function when I create the new Web Workers object?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

When I create a web workers like the following...

```
 var w = new Worker("./Scripts/sample.js");
```

sample.js want to some parameters from the caller!!
Possible?

Comment: what do you want to do with that?No u cant.

Comment: The worker is looping at certain intervals using the method "function Sleep(ms)"  which I created. I want to set the "ms" value when I create the worker. Like when you want to loop it fast, you set short time to "ms" and when you want to loop it slow, you set long time to "ms".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't used web workers a whole bunch, but per [this description](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) I believe you could do it along these lines:

```
var worker = new Worker("sample.js");
worker.postMessage({ "args": [ ] });
```

Then, in sample.js, structure it along these lines:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  var args = e.data.args;
  // do whatever you need with the arguments
}, false);
```

This isn't quite the same as a traditional argument passing, as whatever goes in postMessage must be formattable as a JSON (e.g. no functions). But, there's a decent chance it can be made to do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass arguments in the query string and in sample.js get the arguments from  `location.search`.  You do not need to call postMessage to accomplish this.

## Example Code

Calling code would be

```
var w = new Worker("./Scripts/sample.js?answer=42&question=ultimate");
```

This will call the worker.  In sample.js `location.search` will equal `?answer=42&question=ultimate`.  We can use the following code to pull it out gracefully

```
var parameters = {}
location.search.slice(1).split("&").forEach( function(key_value) { var kv = key_value.split("="); parameters[kv[0]] = kv[1]; })

var question = parameters['question'];
var answer = parameters['answer'];
```

## Live Example

You can see a live example [here](https://panchishin.github.io/worker/page.html)

## Final Thoughts

If you have a *large* amount of data to send, don't use the query string.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer, but don't you think repeating the Question is unnecessary?

Comment: akauppi I've had several cases where the OP changes the question then I get downvotes for giving an off-topic answer or not answering the question.  I don't know how else to address that

Comment: Guess you can't (and I understand). However, if everyone starts repeating the questions on SO it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2):

#### 2018-July

`location` is available in WebWorkers ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope)), which opens up `location.hash`, `location.search`, and even `location.pathname` as ways of passing information. (Tested on Mac OSX in Chrome, Safari, FireFox)

Also, hash and query arguments worked in Chrome and FireFox for `URL.createObjectURL(Blob([src]))`, but not Safari.

(Apologies for the necroposting; search results are forever!)

Comment: Except hash and search aren't implemented except Firefox - error on #, no data on ?. Name should be available soon, and we could use that. Maybe we will be able to get to the constructor bag - `new Worker([path], { type:"module", name:"parameters", bagparameter1:"value1", bagparameter2:"value2"  });`