# HTML5 WebWorker send & receive Number

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

1. How to send a number to webworker ?
2. How to receive a number in webworker ?

if possible, How to do this without using json or javascript Object, because using it will add extra line of code ..

**EDIT :**

ew i got many downvote without knowing why .. i explain what i try to do..

i try to create timer in webworker

- if i send string "start" to webworker, webworker will begin the
  interval(  the timer )
- if i send a number to webworker, webworker will set the duration of
  interval

but i don't know how to send a number,

i knew argument passed to webworker should be a string, i already read few tutorial,

but i still don't understand what to do so my webworker can recognize a number..

because i try parseInt() and is not work ..

here's my code

**in HTML**

```
window.onload = function(){

            var worker = new Worker("Thread.js");
            worker.postMessage("1500");     //set duration of interval
            worker.postMessage("start");    //start the interval


            worker.onmessage = function(e){
                document.body.innerHTML += '<p> worker receive: '+e.data+'</p>';
            }

            worker.onerror = function(e){
                document.body.innderHTML += "<p> worker error"+e.data+"</p>";
            }

    }
```

**Thread.js**

```
onmessage = function(e){

    var msg =  e.data ;
    var timer;
    var duration = 1000;    //default duration

    try{
        var number = parseInt(msg);
        msg = number;
    }catch(e){

    }

    //start the interval
    if(msg === "start"){
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            postMessage( "lalala" );
        }, duration);
    }

    else if(msg === "stop"){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    //set duration
    else if(!isNaN(msg)){
        duration = msg;
    }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019230/javascript-web-workers-how-do-i-pass-arguments

Comment: The MDN has a nice tutorial about the WebWorker API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: What's the problem with what you posted?

Comment: @CanŞahinBakır @ meskobalazs thank u for the reference sir.. but i still don't understand what to do ... i edit my question so it can more clear

Comment: @SebastienC. it doing nothing in chrome.. it should be add paragraph in document.body each interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work because `parseInt` doesn't throw an Error, it returns `NaN` (Not a Number).

You also have another bug: you need to declare `timer` and `duration` outside `onmessage` if you want both to persist between two messages.

Note that changing `duration` won't affect the interval unless you restart it.

```
var timer;
var duration = 1000;

onmessage = function(e) {
    var msg = e.data ;
    var number = parseInt(msg);

    if(msg === "start") {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            postMessage( "lalala" );
        }, duration);
    } else if(msg === "stop") {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else if(!isNaN(msg)) {
        duration = number;
    }
};
```

Comment: billion of thanks  sir.. forgive my stupidity.. it make sense now