# Web Worker in cordova - is it supported

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, web-worker

I can't seem to get my cordova app to execute even a simple web worker, even though the same web worker works in the Chrome browser on the same device.

(Android device, Google Pixel 3, running Android 9, latest patch level. The app was built in PhoneGap build with `cli-8.0.0`)

Setup in the main thread:

```
const worker = new Worker('/fake.worker.js');
worker.postMessage(1337);
worker.addEventListener('message', event => console.log("[myWorker] received event from myWorker:", event));
```

And the `/fake.worker.js` file is just this, no transpilation:

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */
console.log("fake.worker booted");
self.addEventListener("message", startCounter);

function startCounter(event) {
    console.log(event.data, self)
    let initial = event.data;
    console.log("fake.worker counter started:", initial);

    setInterval(() => this.postMessage(initial++), 1000);
}
```

Bottom line, the console never shows anything from the worker, either from the main thread or from the worker thread's `console.log` statements.

While attached to the device and remote debugging, I can see that `('Worker' in window) === true` and that the Network tab of the remote console that the `fake.worker.js` file is indeed loaded. (Serving the file via `ngrok` from my development laptop - after connecting to the remote console, I changed the location of the web view with `window.location.href = 'https://....ngrok...'`.)

*Note*: I also tried including the Web Worker via an inline blob (`worker-loader` for webpack automated this for me, but the concept is shown at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Embedded_workers) - and even when "embedded", the worker never booted.

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642547/phonegap-and-webworkers).

Comment: Any support for saying it works or tips on how to make it work? Because I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: My comment has a hyperlink.

Comment: I do see that the linked "yes" comments assume it's working. However, empirically I have evidence to the contrary and cannot seem to even get the Web Worker to start. Looking for any advice on just getting the web worker to start.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in the `console.log` line

Comment: You're right, it would be good form to add the semicolon. However, it is not required: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Automatic_semicolon_insertion