# How to make a javascript variable defined in javascript worker?

Tags: javascript, promise, web-worker

I have this variable in a javascript file `editorArea.js`.

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'), {});
```

when I call this variable from another javascript worker file `worker.js` inside of a promise.

```js
myPromise.then(() => {
editor.doFunction()
}
```

the variable `example` is undefined.

How to make it defined?

Comment: I think you have to provide more information. Workers and the "main" code are running in isolation.

Comment: why would a string have a method doSomething? Show a better example so we can see your actual problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @FelixKling I have provided a better example

Comment: @epascarello I have provided a better example

Comment: @Quentin I have provided a better example

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019230/javascript-web-workers-how-do-i-pass-arguments

Comment: @mpm I dont think I need to post messages between my main and my worker

Comment: Ah yes you do. You will not in fact be able to use editor, though, since it is a DOM element, and you cannot use DOM objects in a worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web workers have some big limitations - necessary ones since the DOM was never designed with thread safety in mind. You cannot access global variables in the main code, or anything in the DOM from a web worker, and you will find that trying anything in a web worker like editor.doFunction() will not work. The scopes are hermetically sealed off from one another. Instead, you need to send messages to the worker via postMessage, and receive replies via onMessage per [javascript web workers - how do I pass arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019230/javascript-web-workers-how-do-i-pass-arguments) (as suggested by mpm).

The data you pass cannot be DOM elements or anything in the DOM at all or you would violate thread safety. Instead you need to extract any data you need to do heavy duty work on into a separate object and pass it to the worker to process.

As examples, in an application I work on, I pass data for image processing and OCR to web workers for concurrent processing in order not to freeze the UI thread. But I have to copy the data out of the DOM first.